# How to make permanent Bitcoin Address for donations?

Tags: address-reuse, donation

I want to add a `Donate Bitcoin` button to my website(s). I want to create a Bitcoin wallet with a permanent address for receiving donations. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just generate a new address and put it on your website. Not sure what you mean by permanent, all addresses are permanent as long as you keep the private key safe.

Comment: My address changes every time I press `receive`.

Comment: But there's nothing stopping you reusing ones you've already generated, by clicking receive you are generating more, but not replacing the old ones

Comment: But that means that the number of addresses is limited...

Comment: No, you can generate any number of addresses you want to

Comment: But if addresses aren't replaced, than there is a theoretical limited amount.

Comment: Yes, but that limit is massive, so high that it's **never** going to be reached. There are 2^160 possible bitcoin addresses, an incomprehensibly large number

Comment: What's the difference between using a generated address and using an "Extended Public Address"?

Comment: Please start a new separate question, that is unrelated to this question

Comment: Suggesting to reuse addresses it pretty bad for privacy, but it's certainly the easiest way.

Comment: Some web wallets only allow single use of addresses. Once the first deposit is received you need to contact support to have any additional deposits credited.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a web wallet. Install Bitcoin Core or Electrum on your workstation and create a new receiving address, it will be valid permanently.

Re-using addresses is a privacy reduction but, there is no easily implemented alternative if placing a button on a web page unless you are tech savvy to setup a backend script.

Set a strong, secure password that you will never forget on your wallet to limit who can send payments. Ensure that you make a safe, secure and verified backup of your wallet and/or your wallet seed phrase and keep it up to date.